# I am looking for software that can parse emails and expect emails within a grace period

Tags: email, backup, windows-server-backup, logparser, parsing

I manage a diverse set of backup systems, the only commonality is email notifications, There status being Failed, Success, Success with exceptions and unknown(where the email isn't sent).

**Case 1) Expect email from system3@example.net every day, at least once a day.**

This would catch those instances where the backup server went offline, internet outage, or another unforeseen issue that prevented the backup from run and send out a notification of success/fail.

**Case 2) Backup Ran but failed**

The backup ran, but failed, and an email went out stating such event occurred.

**Case 3) Backup Success**

Great, the thing did what it was suppose to do.

**If Case 1 or 2, notify me, if case 3, log for audit**

The application would email me on failure, weekly status reports of all events (simple HTML email would suffice, tables with servers, days and status of each day)

Update: **strictly looking for email based solutions,** template assignments for each email address may be needed to properly parse different backup types, I'll list some systems here:
FreePBX, BackupExec, Appassure, WinSCP Scripts, CrushFTP alerts, qnap sync, syncback software, rsync solutions, Classic windows backup, Bash Expect scripts (to log-in and backup routers via ssh/expect), monthly maintenance tasks like battery backup tests, and other unknown items that would give the same 3 options

Comment: questions: 1) If these emails are not currently notifying you, where are they being directed? 2) do you control the server that handles said emails?

Comment: I currently receive these in my inbox, however I have to maintain a list (paper or excel) so I know which servers didn't actually complete.

I strictly want to do this with email, as there are so many variables with the multiple types of backups, the only consistency is email.

Comment: I've been looking for something like this too, to reduce the amount of emails I have to look through on a regular basis...never seen anything that does it off the shelf, but probably not that hard to use fetchmail to pass emails into a script that parses them, then pass that into whatever monitoring or log parsing system you already have.

Comment: If a solution doesn't exist, I may hack something together with php/mysql and put it on github, with tech my thought has always been  "if I can think of it, someone else probably built it better"

Comment: This sounds exactly like what you're looking for (disclaimer: I'm one of the developers), and you can use it for free for a small company: https://www.checkcentral.cc